# I have 7 rows when I out the page and go again to the same page it show 14 rows

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem, when I run the code it works but when I out from the page and go back it show x2 for the rows its looping without any loop I make in my database 7 rows when I out and return to the same page it shows 14 rows but I have onlu 7 rows.

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class my_ads extends StatefulWidget {
  const my_ads({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<my_ads> createState() => _my_adsState();
}

List list = [];
int select_item = 0;

class _my_adsState extends State<my_ads> {
  @override
  Future MyAds() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://***.***.***.**/getData.php'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var red = jsonDecode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        list.addAll(red);
      });
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load Ads');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    GetData();
  }

  GetData() async {
    await MyAds();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, right: 60, top: 50),
            height: 54.0,
            width: 224.0,
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border:
                        Border.all(color: const Color(0xffF4AC47), width: 5),
                    color: const Color(0xff42A9D2),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(40))),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "MyAds",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        color: Color(0xff072A52),
                        fontFamily: 'Cairo'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  //end logo
                )),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 35,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: ((cts, i) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      height: 180.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: const Color(0xff42A9D2), width: 5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/book.jpg"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 6,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "${list[i]["book_name"]}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black87),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("${list[i]["collage"]}"),
                                      const Icon(Icons.perm_identity_rounded)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      Text("${list[i]["loc"]}"),
                                      const Icon(Icons.store)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add this method to my PHP code `$mysqli_connect-> close();`

But its not working

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = "SELECT book_name,loc,com,spe,collage FROM ads";
$res = $connect->query($sql);

while($row = $res -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

$mysqli_connect-> close();
?>
```

Comment: just reassign  list = red   instead of adding list.addAll(red);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared list outside. It will maintain its state even when you change screens.
Either you declared it inside the state widget or replace :

```
list.addAll(red);
```

by :

```
list = red;
```